# get time from iis

Tags: c#

I want to capture last login time of user  using IIS logs using c#.

I have entry there like:

```
  2013-01-24 00:01:00 ::1 GET /WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/TridionDashboard/TridionDashboard.aspx - 81 TRIDION\user123 ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.1+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/21.0.1180.89+Safari/537.1 200 0 0 48
```

Can anyone tell me the query to get list of user id's with their timestamps after a particular datetime..

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps include some examples of what you have tried

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of log file analysis tools which can get this information for you. What language are you looking to use?

Please be aware that that page gets called quite a lot, and is not always called when someone logs into Tridion from a specific link to a page or component etc.

If that is all you need, (whilst not supported) you might consider adding a script to that page which actually logs the info that you need to a database or something. Better still consider creating a GUI extension for it.

If you really must use the logfiles, take a look at the following article about querying log files with LINQ: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84468/linq-to-log-files/

Comment: thanks Chris.... first of all i am using C#..
Can you tell me which type of GUI extension i can implement here to get real time login information and how?
Thanks

Comment: Hi Aquarius, it seems like most of your posts in the last week have been related to this challenge. It sounds like you need some Professional Services help. So is really not a good platform for this kind of support. If you have a specific programming question, this is the correct place. Questions like "Please do all my homework for me" are beyond the scope of free community support here on SO i'm afraid.